# react native styled components: (tag.text || "").trim is not a function

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I just started a simple react-native app and tried to start an styled component container like so:

```
 import styled from "styled-components/native";


export const Container = styled.View`
    margin-top: 200px;
`;
```

But whatever I type inside Container or any other const, any other react native tag (Button, Pressable, TouchableOpacity, etc) it shows this error:

[image]

On my component there's:

```
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from './container/ButtonContainer'  

interface Btn {
    text: string,
    click: () => void,
}

export default function ButtonComponent({text, click}: Btn ) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={click}
      >
       <Text>
       {text}
       </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

And I already have @types/styled-components-react-native and @types/styled-components installed. What should I do?